# Preferences window does not re-open once closed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window, preferences

I have a button that when clicked opens a Preferences window:

```
-(IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender
{
    if (!prefController) {
        prefController = [[PreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
        [prefController showWindow:self];
}
```

}

However, upon closing the Preferences window, clicking on the button again does not re-open the window. Can someone teach me how to solve this? thanks xD

Comment: ok solved it.

somehow the effect of axing the window does this:
[[prefController prefWindow] setIsVisible:NO];

so doing this brings it back:
[[prefController prefWindow] setIsVisible:YES];

thanks Michael for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer (which usually solves most of these kinds of issues)

Turn ***OFF*** the "Release When Closed" checkbox for that window in Interface Builder and you should be okay.

[image]

My answer #2)

Put that `[prefController showWindow:self];` line ***OUTSIDE*** of the `if (!prefController)` context (i.e. so that `showWindow` gets called each time `openPreferences` is called).

Or, to be more clear:

```
-(IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender
{
    if (!prefController) {
        prefController = [[PreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
    }
    [prefController showWindow:self];
}
```

Comment: ah, I see where the problem is.  Subtle!  Call `showWindow` each and every time the `openPreferences` action is called.

Comment: running [prefController showWindow:self]; the second time doesnt reopen the window. so im afraid your second answer doesnt help too. :(

Comment: I'm out of ideas for now. Something else may be going on with your code. Is prefController null or not null when you call `showWindow` on it?

Comment: it's not null. the app goes through the if (!prefcontroller) loop the first time the button is clicked but not the second.

Comment: @dragoncharmer: That's the problem. See Michael's edit to his answer.